# TeamSpeak on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04, teamspeak

I am trying to run TeamSpeak on ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty Zapus).

I installed TeamSpeak via: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ts3linuxinstall/files/latest/download

Possibly the only way in ubuntu 17.04, but when I try to run it this is the terminal output:

```
./ts3client_linux_x86: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it installed by:
Download the latest and greatest here: 
 http://www.teamspeak.de/en/download/

Move that file to your HOME folder (yes it will make a new folder).

Then in terminal type this:

```
sudo sh TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.1.4.run
```

It will start the install.  Then it will ask you to accept the license agreement (that is what stops it from running from a GUI)  "Q" to exit then agree to it.

To run TS3  I run it from the terminal by:

```
cd TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64
sh ts3client_runscript.sh
```

That worked for me.  Good luck.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/GGUiuyl.jpg