# Team Speak 3 on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: 17.04, teamspeak

I have tried to download TeamSpeak 3 on this version of Ubuntu in many different ways, and saddly all of them are't working. 
For example I tried the way to install Team Speak on 16.04 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJ-aahBoUyo&t=188s) many says that it works and not for me but even thougt I set the team speak file to run as a program it still repeats that it cann'ot find the command.

I also tried both ways from [TeamSpeak on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908145/teamspeak-on-ubuntu-17-04), and it still doensn't work :(.
If you could help me, that would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: btw sorry for mistakes, I was writing it quickly and I don't know english perfectly.

Comment: when you executed `sudo sh TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.1.4.run` did it give you any error messages?  What happens when you `cd TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64; sh ts3client_runscript.sh`

Comment: Charles Green omg, I did both of the commands and it is working, I am very thankful ;)

Comment: but I have a question.. is it possible to make an icon that will take me straight to the ts3 instead of doing it through terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Teamspeak and creating TeamSpeak3 .desktop file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984758/installing-teamspeak-and-creating-teamspeak3-desktop-file)

Answer (score 0):

- [Download](https://www.teamspeak.de/en/download/teamspeak-3-amd64-client-linux/) it. I assume it downloaded to `~/Downloads` folder.

  ```
  ls ~/Downloads/ | grep Team
  TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.5.1.run
  ```
- `chmod +x ~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.5.1.run`
- Run it (no need to put `sh` before it): `~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.5.1.run`
- Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then hit <kbd>q</kbd>, then input `y` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
  `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux-amd64` folder appears in `Downloads` folder.
- `mkdir ~/.local/share/teamspeak`
- `mv ~/Downloads/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64 ~/.local/share/teamspeak/`
- Check if it could be launched:

  ```
  ~/.local/share/teamspeak/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
  ```
- Create shortcut to run it from launcher:

  1. Create the file: `gedit ~/.local/share/applications/teamspeak.desktop` with the next content:

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Name=TeamSpeak3
     Comment=TeamSpeak3 Client
     Exec=/home/user/.local/share/teamspeak/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
     Icon=/home/user/.local/share/teamspeak/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/styles/default/logo-128x128.png
     Terminal=false
     Type=Application
     Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;P2P;
     ```
  2. `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/teamspeak.desktop`

     [image]

     [image] [image]