# Installing Teamspeak and creating TeamSpeak3 .desktop file

Tags: gnome, launcher

I am very new to Ubuntu and I want to create desktop launcher.

I have this in my TeamSpeak3.desktop in

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=TeamSpeak 3
Comment=TeamSpeak 3 VoIP Communicator
Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Application;
Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/styles/default/logo-128x128.png
```

in my `~/.local/share/applications/TeamSpeak3.desktop`
But I dont see it in my launcher and when I double click on it files, it just opens the text file. I even made it executable with
    `chmod +x TeamSpeak3.desktop`

```
drwx------ 15 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 pro  9 19:22 ..
-rw-------  1 hung hung   174627 srp 16 12:29 CHANGELOG
-rwx------  1 hung hung   227136 srp 16 12:29 error_report
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 gfx
drwx------  3 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 html
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 iconengines
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 imageformats
-rwx------  1 hung hung   334520 srp 16 12:29 libc++abi.so.1
-rwx------  1 hung hung  1934744 srp 16 12:29 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rwx------  1 hung hung   746960 srp 16 12:29 libc++.so.1
-rwx------  1 hung hung  5842312 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Core.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   484832 srp 16 12:29 libQt5DBus.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung  5683224 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Gui.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung  1335584 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Network.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   290008 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Positioning.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung  3829280 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Qml.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung  3831288 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Quick.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   234552 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Sql.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   331232 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Svg.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   117104 srp 16 12:29 libQt5WebChannel.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung 67570152 srp 16 12:29 libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   208344 srp 16 12:29 libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung  6439120 srp 16 12:29 libQt5Widgets.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung  1334528 srp 16 12:29 libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
-rwx------  1 hung hung   180248 srp 16 12:29 libquazip.so
-rwx------  1 hung hung    22936 srp 16 12:29 libsnappy.so.1
-rwx------  1 hung hung   111888 srp 16 12:29 libsrtp.so.0
-rwx------  1 hung hung   383072 srp 16 12:29 libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwx------  1 hung hung    51080 srp 16 12:29 libudev.so.0
-rw-------  1 hung hung     4340 srp 16 12:29 openglblacklist.json
-rwx------  1 hung hung   260232 srp 16 12:29 package_inst
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 platforms
-rw-------  1 hung hung       26 srp 16 12:29 qt.conf
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 qtwebengine_locales
-rwx------  1 hung hung    19720 srp 16 12:29 QtWebEngineProcess
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 resources
drwx------  6 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 sound
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 soundbackends
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 sqldrivers
drwx------  3 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 styles
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 translations
-rwx------  1 hung hung 18987008 srp 16 12:29 ts3client_linux_amd64
-rwx------  1 hung hung     1364 srp 16 12:29 ts3client_runscript.sh
-rwx------  1 hung hung  2206064 srp 16 12:29 update
drwx------  2 hung hung     4096 srp 16 12:29 xcbglintegrations
```

Comment: yes, i am, i have used it .. it does the same when i try to open my steam.desktop. I think i have somewhere disabled how to open .desktop, but i have no idea where to look

Comment: no, only after i added it into ~/Desktop

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ls -la /opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/`. [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: i added the output of the command you wanted

Comment: Ok as I thought. So you have run that Teamspeak.run file in your home dir and then moved it to /opt/? then i will write an answer for you covering the whole process of making it work, because your .desktop file is ok as it is.

Comment: I ran Teamspeak.run from my Download folder, is there a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok you have some things wrong in your whole setup and like this it can not really work so I'm going through the whole installation process for you so you can pick up where you got astray.

1. download the `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.1.6.run` from [The Teamspeak Website](https://www.teamspeak.com/en/downloads)
2. run the `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.1.6.run` file with:

   ```
   chmod 755 TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.1.6.run
   ./TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.1.6.run
   ```
3. move the whole new directory to `/opt` with

   ```
   sudo mv TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64 /opt/
   ```
4. change the ownership of the moved copy and recursively change the file permissions with:

   ```
   sudo chown -Rv root:root /opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64
   sudo chmod -Rv 755 /opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64
   ```
5. download some nice icon for Teamspeak, since the provided does not really look good, google simply for `teamspeak ico png` and download one and move it to the `/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64` and name it appropriately; I have chosen here simply `teamspeak-icon.png`
6. create your `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` (you can copy and paste the whole code-block to the terminal):

   ```
   sudo su &&
   cat > /usr/share/applications/teamspeak.desktop << EOF
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=TeamSpeak 3
   Comment=TeamSpeak 3 VoIP Communicator
   Exec=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/ts3client_runscript.sh
   Terminal=false
   Type=Application
   Categories=Network;Application;
   Icon=/opt/TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64/teamspeak-icon.png
   EOF
   exit
   ```

This should leave you with a working Teamspeak client working for every user on the system.