# TeamSpeak 3 startup

Tags: teamspeak

I have installed TeamSpeak 3 on ubuntu according to this [manual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/908145/teamspeak-on-ubuntu-17-04).

After typing

```
sh ts3client_runscript.sh
```

I get

```
ts3client_runscript.sh: 3: ts3client_runscript.sh: Bad substitution
QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
```

and this error from the GUI

```
Unable to load CA certificate
```

How can I fix this? I also tried to start windows version from wine, but I got an exception.

Comment: https://forum.teamspeak.com/threads/134529-Error-Please-instantiate-the-QApplication-object-first-on-Debian-with-3-1-5-and-later seems the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked certificate installation, and realized that I only had to type

```
sudo apt-get remove ca-certificate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificate
```